The American Style
Find the 7-letter word given the image below.



The people are:

 Movie directors and from left to right you have: JOHN CAMERON MITCHELL, HERBERT ROSS, PETER SEGAL and FRANK DARABONT.

The squares below

 are to be filled with one their movies each in that order with respects to an increasing size in terms of measurement units hinted at by the < sign : Hedgewig and the Angry Inch, Footloose, The Longest Yard and The Green Mile.
 Notice how the colours in order of the rainbow colours and the units overlap…


 Next index the letters in order of the numbers and you get LENGTHS!

The title

 Refers to: for measuring length, the U.S. customary system uses the inch, foot, yard, and mile, which are the only four customary length measurements in everyday use.


Fast :) well done!

You have to be fast here lol!
